# Delay Activity in SharePoint State Machine Workflow

Tags: workflow

I Have created one State Machine workflow with delay activity (24 Hours) on Item creation and on Item change.

When Item is Added into custom list my workflow has started with delay activity.

My concern is that in between 24 hours if item is changed by another workflow then

My State Machine workflow will not start again as i already set it on Item change event.

It would be better to Share any approach or idea on this

Thanks

Darshit Gajjar